# Is there any way to get source code with resource of itext in action

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I'm new to digital signature.
I want to create an example.
After lots of research I found this code:

[iText part3/chapter12 Signatures.java](http://examples.itextpdf.com/src/part3/chapter12/Signatures.java)

But due to my lack of knowledge, I can't figure out and make my own resource.
Is there any way to find resources which define in this code.

So I can directly execute it and examine the result and understand it?

Comment: There's a big "sources" archive here: http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the ["learn"](http://itextpdf.com/learn) page on the [official iText site](http://itextpdf.com/), you will find a link to a free ebook entitled [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html).

All the examples that are mentioned in this book are available on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/). Most of these examples (not all of them, due to differences inherent to the different programming languages) are ported to C# and also published on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/).

As for the examples from [Chapter 12 of iText in Action - Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=12). You can still find them on the [book page](http://itextpdf.com/book/), but they have been adapted to the most recent specifications with respect to digital signatures. The iText in Action books are more than 5 years old. The digital signatures created using the original examples are no longer supported. They aren't compliant with the PAdES standard and they will be deprecated in PDF 2.0.

I am chairing a sub-committee of the ISO committee responsible for ISO-32000-2 (aka PDF 2.0, due in 2016). Yesterday, we finalized the section regarding digital signatures. I can confirm that PKCS#1 signatures and the subfilters `adbe.x509.rsa_sha1` and `adbe.pkcs7.sha1` are deprecated (as in: you should no longer use them).