# Itext signed pdf error when executing program

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I want to perform digital signature program and make signed pdf.
For that 
1.  I use following source code
[Java Code](http://examples.itextpdf.com/src/part3/chapter12/Signatures.java)
2.  For certificate create self signed certificate using this link and export to pfx.
[How to create self signed certi](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx)
3.  Now try to execute following program but still give following error

```
    /*
 * This class is part of the book "iText in Action - 2nd Edition"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie (ISBN: 9781935182610)
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/examples/
 * This example only works with the AGPL version of iText.
 */
package iText;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateVerification;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.VerificationException;

public class Signatures {

    /**
     * The resulting PDF
     */
    public static String ORIGINAL = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\hello.pdf";
    /**
     * The resulting PDF
     */
    public static String SIGNED1 = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\signature_1.pdf";
    /**
     * The resulting PDF
     */
    public static String SIGNED2 = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\signature_2.pdf";
    /**
     * Info after verification of a signed PDF
     */
    public static String VERIFICATION = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\verify.txt";
    /**
     * The resulting PDF
     */
    public static String REVISION = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\revision_1.pdf";

    /**
     * A properties file that is PRIVATE. You should make your own properties
     * file and adapt this line.
     */
    public static String PATH = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DigiSig\\src\\digisig\\key.properties";
    /**
     * Some properties used when signing.
     */
    public static Properties properties = new Properties();

    /**
     * One of the resources.
     */
    //   public static final String RESOURCE = "resources/img/logo.gif";
    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     *
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     *
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public void signPdfFirstTime(String src, String dest)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
//        String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
//        String keystore_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
//        String key_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
        String path = "C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\kandarp.pfx";
        String keystore_password = "kandarp";
        String key_password = "kandarp";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
        String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        // reader and stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        // appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
//        appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE));
        appearance.setReason("I've written this.");
        appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1, "first");
        // digital signature
        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     *
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public void signPdfSecondTime(String src, String dest)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String path = "resources/encryption/.keystore";
        String keystore_password = "f00b4r";
        String key_password = "f1lmf3st";
        String alias = "foobar";
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        // reader / stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
        // appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper
                .getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason("I'm approving this.");
        appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(160, 732, 232, 780), 1, "second");
        // digital signature
        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    }

    /**
     * Verifies the signatures of a PDF we've signed twice.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void verifySignatures() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        FileInputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("ROOTCERT"));
        X509Certificate cert1 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("cacert", cert1);
        FileInputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("resources/encryption/foobar.cer");
        X509Certificate cert2 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is2);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("foobar", cert2);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(VERIFICATION));
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SIGNED2);
        AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
        ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            out.println("Signature name: " + name);
            out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
            out.println("Document revision: " + af.getRevision(name) + " of " + af.getTotalRevisions());
            PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
            Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
            Certificate[] pkc = pk.getCertificates();
            out.println("Subject: " + CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
            out.println("Revision modified: " + !pk.verify());
            List<VerificationException> errors = CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(pkc, ks, null, cal);
            if (errors.size() == 0) {
                out.println("Certificates verified against the KeyStore");
            } else {
                out.println(errors);
            }
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the first revision of a PDF we've signed twice.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void extractFirstRevision() throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SIGNED2);
        AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(REVISION);
        byte bb[] = new byte[1028];
        InputStream ip = af.extractRevision("first");
        int n = 0;
        while ((n = ip.read(bb)) > 0) {
            os.write(bb, 0, n);
        }
        os.close();
        ip.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\02948\\Desktop\\kandarp.pfx");
        String password = "kandarp";
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(PATH));
        Signatures signatures = new Signatures();
        signatures.createPdf(ORIGINAL);
        signatures.signPdfFirstTime(ORIGINAL, SIGNED1);
        signatures.signPdfSecondTime(SIGNED1, SIGNED2);
        signatures.verifySignatures();
        signatures.extractFirstRevision();
    }
}
```

4. Error comes . pl help

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature.<init>(PrivateKeySignature.java:77)
   at iText.Signatures.signPdfFirstTime(Signatures.java:135)
   at iText.Signatures.main(Signatures.java:252)
   ```

   Java Result: 1
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Are you sure that `pk` isn't null? Did you test this?

Comment: If you shared your pfx file (as it is a self-signed entity, that should not be an issue), we could possibly reproduce the issue.

Comment: You were referred to [this free book](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) in which I explain how to create a public/private key pair using the Java `keytool` utility. You don't create much goodwill when you ignore the advice previously given. Why aren't you using `keytool` as explained in the free ebook? Why didn't you accept the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642401/is-there-any-way-to-get-source-code-with-resource-of-itext-in-action

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. Changing the Security.Provider At the time of creating KeyStore works.
Either change your code from

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
```

to

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
```

or use any Other Provider: SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJSSE, SunJGSS
More info about Provider class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html